# Open a file in python using Atom-editor

Tags: python

```
x = open('ml.txt')
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

Error is :`No such file or directory: 'ml.txt'`

I have this error when I run it in Atom-editor, but It works fine when I run it from the command prompt or with python idle.

also I'm using windows 10.

one more thing, Atom-editor,python, ml.txt, and the file that I'm running the program from are all saved in the same file

Comment: if you do import os; print(os.getcwd()) does it come up in the same directory as your file?

Comment: try specifying how you want to deal with the file. e.g `x = open('ml.txt', 'r')`

Comment: I think @ch4rl1e97 might be right, check if python interpreter is opened in the folder where is the file or use full file address

Comment: @ch4rl1e97 It is different than the file. what should I do?

Comment: You may switch the working directory using `os.chdir("C:\\your\\file\\location")` where your file is in the folder "location" in this example. It may be that Atom will let you set the working/home directory in a setting somewhere. Unfortunately I can't help further as I do not use Atom myself.